# Changing styles for "Sign in with Google" button on mobile

Tags: css, google-signin

I'm using "Sign in with Google" following the Google Identity API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview).

It appears that once the button manages to make a successful connection to Google, it creates its own iframe and resets all the styling.

This (whilst being annoying) is fine for desktop as their "[Generate Integration Code](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator)" feature from the docs generates a button that is appropriately sized for desktop viewports.

The issue comes when accessing the site from mobile - it becomes tiny as you'd expect, and there is seemingly no features within Googles own styling to detect this and make it optimised for mobile.

As far as I can tell it's also not possible to use your own media queries as the button is located within an iFrame. So I'm a bit lost as to how I can easily optimise the button to mobile.

I've seen people reference Google's Javascript API and say you have to make your own "Sign in with Google" button then link it to your own JS - but *surely* there is a more intuitive approach than this?

Thanks.